# como usar o SUM dentro de um ORDER BY (mysql)

Tags: mysql

Galera tenho o seguinte select em mysql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.id,
    a.unidade,
    a.posicao,
    a.nome,
    a.peso
FROM
    produtos a,
    produtos_pedidos b
WHERE
    a.id = b.id_produto
    and b.id_pedido IN (13,12,11)
ORDER BY a.nome
```

Bom com ele tenho os produtos dos pedidos 13,12,11 sem repetir em ordem alfabética. Bom o problema e que queria colocar ele em ordem de quantidade, tentei fazer o seguinte select:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.id,
    a.unidade,
    a.posicao,
    a.nome,
    a.peso
FROM
    produtos a,
    produtos_pedidos b
WHERE
    a.id = b.id_produto
    and b.id_pedido IN (13,12,11)
ORDER BY SUM(b.qtd)
```

Porem ele me retorna apenas 1 resultado. Alguém sabe o que eu posso estar fazendo errado.

Comment: O que você está tentando fazer com esse order? Não faz muito sentido ordenar por agrupador sem usar GROUP. Se quer ordem de quantidade, o sum faz ainda menos sentido. Seria mais fácil fazer só `SUM b.qtd`, ou então GROUP BY b.id_pedido. Sugeriria [edit] a pergunta e colocar o problema que quer resolver, e não apenas a forma como está tentando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.id,
    a.unidade,
    a.posicao,
    a.nome,
    a.peso,
    sum(b.qtd) quant
FROM
    produtos a,
    produtos_pedidos b
WHERE
    a.id = b.id_produto
    and b.id_pedido IN (13,12,11)
GROUP BY 
    a.id,
    a.unidade,
    a.posicao,
    a.nome,
    a.peso
ORDER BY
    a.nome
```